# Django decorators with arguments for multiple views

Tags: python, django, decorator

Iam using django decorators in my project. 
Iam using multiple views with arguments and i need to call 1 decorator.

I want only one view to call with its arguments once. But the decorators giving the values of every views wherever i used the decorator.

I want the argument belong to the particular views which i called.

My views and decorator as:

```
def d(msg='my default message'):
    def decorator(func):
        print msg
        def newfn(request, **kwargs):
            return func(request, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator

@d('This is working')
def company_add(request):
   return ...

@d('Dont come')
def company_list(request, comp_id = None):
   return ...
```

If i call company_add views, Iam getting Output as :

```
This is working
Dont come
```

But my expected result is

```
This is working.
```

Anyone help me to print only the argument belong to the particular views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrap function with `@d(arg)`, you actually run the body of the `d` function with `msg=arg` before running decorated function and of course print the `msg`. You can place the  `print` statement somewhere else, for example:

```
def d(msg='my default message'):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(request, **kwargs):
            print msg
            return func(request, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to move `print msg` to the scope of the newfn wrapper. When you call the decorator with an argument specified, it executes and results in the behavior described above.

```
def d(msg='my default message'):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(request, **kwargs):
            print msg # The message should be printed here.
            return func(request, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator
```

Comment: This is exactly my answer)